# If $G=\langle a\rangle $ is a cyclic group of order $12$ and it is generated by $a$. What would the orders of $a^8$ and $a^{10}$ be?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G=\langle a\rangle $ is a cyclic group of order $12$ and it is generated by $a$. What would the orders of $a^8$ and $a^{10}$ be? What would explicitly be the subgroup of $G$ generated by those elements?

Comment: Did you try taking successive powers of the elements? $(x^8)^2=x^{16}=x^4$, $(x^8)^3=\cdots$, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the following holds: if $o(a) = m$ is finite, then $\displaystyle o(a^k) = \frac{m}{(m, k)}$. (This is a bit overkill for your problem but I think it is still good to know.)

**Proof**: Let $d = (m, k)$. Then $m = dm'$, $k = dk'$ for some $m', k' \in \mathbb N$, with $(m', k') = 1$. Furthermore, let $l = o(a^k)$. We shall prove that $l = m'$ by proving that $l | m'$ and $m' | l$.

In fact, $e = (a^k)^l = a^{kl}$, therefore $m | kl$ and substituting we get $dm' | dk'l$, which implies $m' | k'l$. Since $(m', k') = 1$, we have $m' | l$.

Also $$\displaystyle (a^k)^{m'} = a^{km'} = a^{dk'm'} = a^{k'm} = (a^m)^{k'} = e^{k'} = e$$ yields $l | m'$.

Therefore, since $l = m'$, we have $\displaystyle o(a^k) = l = m' = \frac{m}{d} = \frac{m}{(m, k)}$.

---

With $o(a) = m = 12$, we get $\displaystyle o(a^8) = \frac{12}{(12, 8)} = 3$ and $\displaystyle o(a^{10}) = \frac{12}{(12, 10)} = 6$